# Why aren't the questions on this page displaying?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Please have it easy on me on this problem.

I have a table called SurveyQuestions that contains the following columns

```
QuestionId, int;


Questions nvarchar(355);


AnswerType char(1);
```

`AnswerType` can be `M` for multiple choice, `T` for Text and `S` for single answer like radio button choices.

The code below is intended to present the questions in those formats.
However, for some reason, when I run the code, only the image is showing leaving the rest of the page blank.

I have to admit this isn't my code but on the appearance, it doesn't look that complex.

This is the markup for a page called Survey. Sorry for long code.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/logo.gif"></asp:HyperLink></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="100%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table style="width: 100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="height: 21px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    <strong>)</strong>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Columns="30" Font-Bold="False" Rows="5"
                                        TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("AnswerType") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Please answer the following survey questions :"></asp:Label>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Copyright (C) 2006. All rights reserved."></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SurveyQuestions] WHERE ([SurveyID] = @SurveyID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="SurveyID" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

Then relevant code behind:

```
Protected Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles DataList1.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim anstype As HiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1")
        Dim questionid As Label = e.Item.FindControl("Label3")
        Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = e.Item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1")
        Dim cbl As CheckBoxList = e.Item.FindControl("CheckBoxList1")
        Dim txt As TextBox = e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1")
        Dim ds As DataSet = GetDataSet(questionid.Text)
        Select Case anstype.Value
            Case "S"
                rbl.Visible = True
                cbl.Visible = False
                txt.Visible = False
                rbl.DataSource = ds
                rbl.DataTextField = "Choice"
                rbl.DataValueField = "ChoiceID"
                rbl.DataBind()
            Case "M"
                rbl.Visible = False
                cbl.Visible = True
                txt.Visible = False
                cbl.DataSource = ds
                cbl.DataTextField = "Choice"
                cbl.DataValueField = "ChoiceID"
                cbl.DataBind()
            Case "T"
                rbl.Visible = False
                cbl.Visible = False
                txt.Visible = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Where is the markup code?

Comment: I messed with the code formatting.

I think some corrected it for me. 

Thanks @Kevin

Comment: Where are you providing `@SurveyID`?

Comment: @ChidiOkeh Did you provide id in query string? Does your code run if you change the query to `SELECT * FROM [SurveyQuestions]` without `Where Clause`? Can you test in database whether this query `SELECT * FROM [SurveyQuestions]` return any row?

Comment: @Win, I tested it in database and it returns the rows it is supposed to.

I have also ran it without the WHERE clause and page is still blank.

It is puzzling.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh Could you add `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` to `DataList` and test it again?

Comment: I fixed it.

Thanks all for your assistance.

For some reason, removing these below fixed it:

`        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="SurveyID" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just me, but I wouldn't use the `<asp:SqlDatasource />`

In your code behind on `Page_Load` you should do:

```
(pseudocode)

If Not IsPostBack
    DataList1.DataSource = dataSource
    DataList1.DataBind()
End
```

Your `dataSource` variable would be the result of you running the SQL query.

Comment: I am getting:
`Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'DataList1'.  Remove one definition.`

Comment: @ChidiOkeh: Remove the `DataSourceID` from the markup if going this route.

Comment: @Jack, same blank page.

Comment: Does your datasource have data before calling DataBind() ?